# aptana shortcuts for commenting/uncommenting code in php

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana

I just started using Aptana Studio 3.0.1 under Ubuntu 11.04 (64 bit) and I wonder how I can comment lines of code. I already tried to set a shortcut in the preferences->keys menu but it doesn't work. Does anyone have a clue how I can get this work?

Comment: Maybe the keys you assigned are already linked to another command. That could be why it won't work.

Comment: A already thought about that. Aptana says there are no shortcut conflicts but when I use my assignment a small context menu opens up where I can select "add numbers in line/selection".

Comment: Does it work when you select different shortcuts? You may have found a bug. I'd notify Aptana's developers.

Comment: On other shortcuts there's nothing happening. I just thought i was kind of too stupid to adjust the shortcuts.

Comment: Well, I can't be sure from here, but let's assume you're not. :D

Comment: =) thank you. I feel honored. I'll write them a mail.

Comment: I'm also using only Eclipse with the Aptana Plugin, so the following might be not applicable to you: do you have a "Source" menu in the upper menu bar? The first item says "Toggle Comment". Usually there is the corresponding shortcut written next to it. For me it's "Ctrl + Shift + C", although "Ctrl + Shift + 7" does work, too.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how the shortcuts work on the Ubuntu version, but for Windows's Aptana 3.0 you just press Ctrl + / for comment, and uncomment by pressing Ctrl +/ again, just like what smott said.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

> To comment and uncomment use CTRL + ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the english keyboard, but maybe you will find this useful. I comment the code by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + 7 and uncomment by pressing that again. SHIFT + 7 produces the / sign.

Comment: "SHIFT + 7 produces the / sign"
thank you for that little keyboard lesson ;)
that also doesn't work. in my aptana it doesn't anything.

EDIT: I have a German keyboard

Comment: Hehe, I don't know the german keyboard layout, that's why I typed that. :)

Comment: Hehe okay. I just had to laugh about it a bit. It was nothing personal.

Answer (score 0):

I have eclipse, but the comment shortcut is

CTRL+3 for comment
CTRL+\ for uncomment

Again that's my setup. I don't know about yours, and I have never changed mine.

Comment: Try looking under the source menu.

Answer (score 0):

Could be, that you have an non-US-Keyboard-layout? Aptana is been known for being buggy when it comes to the support of other-language-keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

to comment a block of code use CTRL + SHIFT + /

but the mark (/) should be the one inside SHIFT button